# i applied some media query selectors to my css file on my react app but wasn't working

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I was following a react course and i tried apply the media query to my css while using the css module in my app. But unfortunately the media query are not working.

here is my css file:

```
.Burger {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) and (min-height: 400px) {
    .Burger {
        width: 350px;
        height: 300px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) and (min-height: 401px) {
    .Burger {
        width: 450px;
        height: 400px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) and (min-height: 700px) {
    .Burger {
        width: 700px;
        height: 600px;
    }
}

and here is my component code:
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Burger.module.css";
import BurgerIngredient from "./BurgerIngredient/BurgerIngredient";

const burger = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className={classes.Burger}>
            <BurgerIngredient type= "bread-top" />
            <BurgerIngredient type= "cheese" />
            <BurgerIngredient type= "meat" />
            <BurgerIngredient type= "bread-bottom" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default burger;
```

please anyone can help with this because the media query is not working

Comment: - Are the styles that don't rely on `@media` queries working?
- Do other rules, like `background-color: red` work with the `@media` queries?
- When you inspect the .Burger element with dev tools, does it show the `@media` rules under the Styles section?

Comment: Yes, when inspected it does show. i just don't know why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

change min-width to max-width in media queries

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).